# How to compare recursively ignoring given fields using assertJ?

Tags: java, unit-testing, assertj

`AssertJ` has `isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields` and `isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively`.

But, there is no way I can compare two objects recursively by ignoring some fields. As per [this](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/698) discussion, it must be in development.

How to still get my assert's return value to be compared recursively but ignoring some fields. Is it possible in any other library or can I do it somehow using `AssertJ`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I couldn't get it to ignore some fields but I managed to temporarily solve it by introducing a comparator for the fields which I want to ignore and always evaluated them to true. This is not fluent but a temporary solution to get the job done.

```
assertThat(object).usingComparatorForFields((x,y)->0,"field1","field2").isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(expectedObject);
```

This has an [issue](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/973) as of April 13, 2017. [It doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370317/how-does-assertjs-usingcomparatorforfields-work?noredirect=1&lq=1) when the fields which the comparator is trying to compare are null. This is an issue when one of objects is `null` not if both are `null`.

Comment: I marked my answer as accepted because when I had the problem with a particular version, I solved it using that way. But, I'd recommend any new comers to check [Ovidiu Nistor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4602948/ovidiu-nistor) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55090416/4669984) as it is better to use the Updated versions.

Answer (score 125):

With latest 'Recursive comparison api improvements' from AssertJ release 3.12.0
it's possible now to do a recursive comparison and ignore fields:

```
Assertions.assertThat(objActual)
                .usingRecursiveComparison()
                .ignoringFields("uniqueId", "otherId")
                .ignoringFieldsMatchingRegexes(".*someId")
                .ignoringOverriddenEqualsForTypes(MyData.class, MyDataItem.class)
                .isEqualTo(objExpected);
```

Comment: I marked my answer as accepted because when I had the problem with a particular version, I solved it using that way. But, I'd recommend any new comers to check this particular answer as it is better to use the Updated versions.

Comment: this saved me from headache.

Answer (score 10):

Dunno if that was your exact question, but what used to trip me up a lot was that for the ignoring fields function is that "navigation" to the fields to ignore is not considering array / Iterable boundaries.

That is, if I have a class book that has many pages (e.g. if you have a one-to-many relationship and save it to your relational database), I can ignore the fact that "book.pages" is an array, and just work with "book.pages.id" like there was only one page all the time, like so:

```
assertThat(actualBook)
    .usingRecursiveComparison()
    .ignoringFields("id", "pages.id", "pages.book")
    .isEqualTo(expectedBook);
```

Why is this confusing? Because if you forget to ignore fields, the exception will state that there is a mismatch in, say, "pages[2].id" - but you won't need that index "[2]" in the ignore statement.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.