# How does AssertJ's `usingComparatorForFields` work?

Tags: java, unit-testing, assert, assertj

Related to [How to compare recursively ignoring given fields using assertJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43316133/4669984)

As a work around the problem, I tried to rig the comparator for the field which I don't want the comparator to compare and made it return 0.

```
assertThat(service.postComment(12,234,comment)).usingComparatorForFields((a,b)->0,"startDate").isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(commentReturned);
```

But, still I get this exception.

```
Path to difference:  <startDate>
- expected: <null>
- actual  : <2017-04-12 18:28:06.766>
```

As a sidenote - I don't want to compare startDate because it retrieves current date using legacy `java.util.Date` which compares milli seconds too.

How does it `usingComparatorForFields` work. I even tried it using `isEqualToComparingFieldByField` instead of `isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively` and the error persists (in the same case. This one fails for cases where recursive comparison is required.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug from what I see, what version of AssertJ are you using ?

Can you create an issue in [assertj-core](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues) with a simple test case reproducing the error ?

Comment: I'm using 3.6.2

Comment: Created the issue. [#973](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/973)