# AssertJ: For a Pojo how to check each nested Property/Field in one chained sentence

Tags: junit, assertj

Having a `POJO` such as:

```
public class ClientWebRequest {

    private URI uri;
    private HttpMethod httpMethod;

    private final Header header;
    private final Body body;


    public ClientWebRequest(){
        header = new Header();
        body = new Body();
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

About `JUnit` working with `AssertJ` the following is valid, the `@Test` method pass:

```
assertThat(clientWebRequest).isNotNull();
assertThat(clientWebRequest.getHeader()).isNotNull();
assertThat(clientWebRequest.getHeader().getAccept()).isNotNull();
assertThat(clientWebRequest.getHeader().getAcceptLanguage()).isNull();
assertThat(clientWebRequest.getHeader().getContentType()).isNull();
assertThat(clientWebRequest.getBody()).isNotNull();
assertThat(clientWebRequest.getBody().getBody()).isNull();
```

Even when it works, is verbose in some way.

I want to know *if is possible* rewrite all the above in just one sentence, checking each nested property/field. Thus I have tried for example the following:

```
assertThat(clientWebRequest.getHeader()).isNotNull()
        .hasFieldOrProperty("accept").isNotNull()
        .hasFieldOrProperty("acceptLanguage").isNull();
```

But fails with the following error message:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<null> 
but was:<Header [accept=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], acceptLanguage=null, contentType=null]>
        at
```

My main goal is workaround with `isNotNull` and `isNull` for each property/field of the `POJO`

**Alpha**: Thanks to `Joel`'s suggestion the following works now:

```
assertThat(clientWebRequest).isNotNull()
                            .extracting("header.accept")
                            .doesNotContainNull();

assertThat(clientWebRequest).isNotNull()
        .extracting("header.acceptLanguage", "header.contentType")
       .containsNull();
```

From above (two blocks) If I try the following (one block):

```
assertThat(clientWebRequest).isNotNull()
                            .extracting("header.accept")
                            .doesNotContainNull();
       .extracting("header.acceptLanguage", "header.contentType")
       .containsNull();
```

It fails. Just curious if is possible apply *one* block.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I think the best way is to [extract](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.19.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#extracting(java.lang.String...)) all the properties/fields and then checks it does not contain null.

Example:

```
TolkienCharacter frodo = new TolkienCharacter("Frodo", 33, HOBBIT);

// support nested properties: 
assertThat(frodo).extracting("name", "age", "race.name")
                 .doesNotContainNull()
                 .containsExactly("Frodo", 33, "Hobbit");
```

Note that you can also use [lambdas to extract values](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.19.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#extracting(java.util.function.Function...)) from the object under test.

```
assertThat(frodo).extracting(TolkienCharacter::getName,
                             character -> character.age,
                             character -> character.getRace().getName())
                 .containsExactly("Frodo", 33, "Hobbit");
```

Comment: Thanks, please see the Alpha section added. Not sure if one block is possible.

Comment: That won't work because after applying `extracting` you end up performing assertions on the collection of values corresponding to the extracted properties. If you use `extracting` again it will try to extract properties from each elements of the previous collection of values.

Comment: what will happen if `character.getRace()` is null, wouldn't the test case blow up with NullPointerException?

Comment: For Kotlin users the last line of the first example will look like:
`.containsExactly(Tuple("Frodo", 33, "Hobbit"))`

Comment: From AssertJ 3.12.0 you can use `assertThat(frodo).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(expectedFrolo)`, see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55090416/4214921